# Put focus on a JTextField in JDialog when latter made visible

Tags: java, swing, focus, jdialog

I have a subclass of JDialog... the overridden setVisible method looks like this:

```
public void setVisible( boolean visible ){
    super.setVisible( visible );

    if( visible ){
        inputJTF.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

In fact when I display the JDialog the focus **is** on the JTF... but the latter happens also to be the "first" component (NORTH panel) in the JDialog, so that's not surprising.

But my testing code is telling me other things:

```
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            app.mainFrame.searchDlg.setVisible( true );

            // all 3 of these asserts fail...
            assertTrue( app.mainFrame.searchDlg.inputJTF.hasFocus() );
            Component focusOwner = app.mainFrame.searchDlg.getFocusOwner();
            assertFalse( focusOwner == null );
            assertTrue( String.format( "# focus owner %s", focusOwner.getClass()), focusOwner ==  app.mainFrame.searchDlg.inputJTF );

        }
    });
```

... so in fact I get told that the "focus owner" is null... and the JTF doesn't have focus.  Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha... this turns out to be one of those "Gotcha" things with JUnit and Java GUI.

The test in my code fails ... but the following code doesn't:

```
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            searchDlg.setVisible( true );
            assertTrue( searchDlg.queryString == null );
        }
    });
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay( 10 );
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // now passes
            assertTrue( app.mainFrame.searchDlg.inputJTF.hasFocus() );
        }
    });
```

... if the `robot.delay()` is reduced to 1, or absent, the failure happens.

Clearly this is to do with the finite time needed to realise the `JDialog`.

Rob Camick's answer is interesting, and `RequestFocusListener` works as intended.

However his answer doesn't actually answer the question: which was: what's going on and why does this test fail?

Answer (score 3):

Most dialogs are modal, which means the statement after the setVisible(true) statement is not executed until the dialog is closed.

By default focus will go to the first component on the dialog.

If for some reason you need focus on a different component then check out [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) for a solution that allow you to control which component get focus.

This solution uses an `AncestorListener` to place focus on a component once the component is displayed on a visible dialog/frame.

Comment: "the statement after the setVisible(true) statement is not executed until the dialog is closed"
... OK... explains a lot, thanks.  Have you by any chance got any idea why `getFocusOwner()` would return `null`?  Now checking out your Dialog Focus...

Comment: also, if I may... I'm familiar with setVisible( true ) blocking a thread (even the EDT)... and have spent much time scratching my head over it (new "Event Dispatch pumps", etc.).  But why, in my second code snippet, does it not block THAT EDT thread?

Comment: `But why, in my second code snippet,` - What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? Why do you even care what has focus? FYI, you can't always assume that all code executed sequentially. In the same way you use invokeAndWait(...) other code could use invokeLater(), which means focus may not be determined when your assert statements are executed.  Post a proper `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. Code snippets don't help since we don't understand the context of how the code is used.

Comment: @mikerodent, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I've got to do some experimenting first to find out whether it has been solved really... I'm also thinking of putting together an SSCCE.  But I shall not fail to mark it as solved in due course...